# JOptionsPane displays Components in the 'options' argument as Component.toString()

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm trying to pop up a dialog to allow the user to select one of two colors as a background color. To make it look especially spiffy, I'd like to two choices to be displayed in the color in question, i.e.:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Label;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JOptionPaneTest extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JOptionPaneTest();
    }

    public JOptionPaneTest() {
        Object[] possibilities = new Object[2];
        JButton black = new JButton("Black");
        JButton white = new JButton("White");
        black.setBackground(Color.black);
        white.setBackground(Color.white);
        black.setForeground(Color.white);
        white.setForeground(Color.black);
        possibilities[0] = black;
        possibilities[1] = white;

        JButton l = (JButton)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, 
                "Please specify the background color", "Background check",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, possibilities,
                possibilities[0]);
        System.out.println("" + l);
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work - it displays the JButton.toString() return values in a drop down instead of the JButton. I also tried JLabel and Label for the heck of it. According to the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), the JButtons should be added to the dialog as is since they're Components. If I add the JButton to the 'message' parameter it does display as expected.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java API is slighly unclear about this point. At the top describes how to interpret the `options`, but `options` are the YES, NO, CANCEL... possibilities the user can choose, painted in the buttons row. You are talking about the `selectionValues`, and then the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) (go to last method named `showInputDialog`) is clear:

`selectionValues` - an array of Objects that gives the possible selections
It is up to the UI to decide how best to represent the selectionValues, but usually a JComboBox, JList, or JTextField will be used.

From my experience, the objects passed in the `selectionValues` are displayed using `toString()`and the result is shown in a `JComboBox` or a `JList`, so you can not show selection values with custom painting; you need to implement you own dialog for that.

You can pass the `message` as a `Component` so you can provide a legend to the user about the `selectionValues`, where you can show labels with background colors to indicate each color available and thus provide assitance selecting a value from `selectionValues`.

Comment: With all due respect, the text you quote isn't clear to me - there's nothing in there that says the input is limited to strings. If it were, it'd make much more sense to make the type String[] instead of Object[]. Certainly my experience is the same as yours, though.

Answer (score 0):

Should be array of strings not array of jbutton (possibilites) in showInputDialog, but in this way you won't have background color. I don't think it exists any way to implement such colors chooser in showInputDialog()

```
String[] str = {"aaa", "bbb"};

JButton l = (JButton)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, 
            "Please specify the background color", "Background check",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, str, str[0]);
```

Comment: In the API I linked it clearly says that it can be an array of Components, Icons, or anything else (the latter is converted to a String via toString(). Compenents are added to the dialog as is per the API, so the code I posted ought to work.

Comment: sorry but you shound't trust this API. In this components the most important is toString() method, it doesn't matter if this is swing objects or your objects - all time there is calling toString()